# Is there a way to match 3 colors, alternating, to odd numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I am trying to create a list of 3 phase color coding.

ex **:**

```
Red: 1.
Black: 3.
Blue: 5.
Red: 7.
and so on and so fourth, until 100.
```

Same thing on the even side of numbers.

```
Red: 2
Black: 4
Blue: 6
Red: 8.
```

How would I achieve this in JavaScript?

PS : I am new to coding and have never used stackoverflow yet so apologies.

Comment: please show your expect array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of desired length using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and then fill the array with appropriate colors based on the index.

```js
const 
  evens = ["Red", "Black", "Blue"],
  odds = ["Maroon", "Gray", "Cyan"],
  result = Array.from(
    { length: 20 },
    (_, i) =>
      `${
        i & 1
          ? evens[Math.floor(i / 2) % evens.length]
          : odds[Math.floor(i / 2) % odds.length]
      } = ${i + 1}`
  );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Any way to add the numbers beside the output though? Red: 1, Black: 3, Blue: 5, Red: 7, Black: 9, etc

Comment: @Alex.M Sorry, I didn't get that. Could you please elaborate? You can update the `evens` and `odds` array to hold whatever colors you want.

Comment: when you run your snippet there. The output is just the color no? Im just trying to get the corresponding Color and number together. So the output of the code would show "Red = 1. Black = 3. Blue = 7" etc. not sure if that helps

Comment: @Alex.M Yeah you can, I've updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: wow thanks so much! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to that is to create an array of colors, then just check if even or odd, then use the modulo to identify the iterating colors from start to end.

```js
var arr = []
var even_colors = ["Red", "Black", "Blue"];
var odd_colors = ["Yellow", "Pink", "Orange"]
var index = 0;
var even_counter = 0;
var odd_counter = 0;

for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  if( i % 2 == 0 ){
    // You can perform any action here like DOM manipulation if you can
    arr.push(even_colors[even_counter % 3]);
    even_counter++;
  }else{
    arr.push(odd_colors[odd_counter % 3]);
    odd_counter++;
  }
}

// Or make use of the color array here
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it. How exactly would you run that code though? console.log();?